# Event handler get's called before handler is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have this reusable component in my react app.

```
export const OutsideWrapper = ({ children, onOutside, className }) => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  const [style, setStyles] = useState({
    opacity: 1
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1. component was mounted");
    const i = e => {
      if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log("3. outside click was trigerred");
        e.preventDefault();
        setStyles({ opacity: 0 });
        setTimeout(() => {
          onOutside();
        }, 100);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", i, true);
    console.log('2. listener was added');
    return () => {
      console.log("4. listerner was removed");
      window.removeEventListener("click", i, true);
    };
  }, [onOutside]);
  return (
    <div
      ref={wrapperRef}
      style={style}
      className={`outside-wrapper ${className}`}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

When this `OutsideWrapper` component get's rendered, it should add event listener to the document, then listen to an event, call `onOutside` function and then unmount. (`onOutside` unmounts the component). After that listener gets removed.

But when component get's rendered, it immediately calls `onOutside` and unmounts.

Here's the part of parent component:

```
const [down, setDown] = useState(false);
return (
    <input onFocus={()=>setDown(true)}/>
       {down && (
          <OutsideWrapper
             onOutside={() => setDown(false)}
             className="input-wrapper"
           >
            <DropDownList
              items={dropDownItems}
              term={data.location}
              onChoose={onChoose}
             />
          </OutsideWrapper>
       )}
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.addEventListener` call inside `useEffect` is being called when React's rendering the component, which happens on *focus*. The event that causes focus isn't the click though, it's a `mousedown`. When the next `mouseup` happens, a click event is also generated which is caught. Notice that if you tab into the input to focus it doesn't cause the bug.

There are a couple approaches to fix this, but my recommendation is to ignore click events that happen on the input itself.

Here's an example: I've added a ref to the `<input>`, passed it into `OutsideWrapper`, and added a check like you have for `wrapperRef` for the new ref.

```
function Test() {
  const [down, setDown] = React.useState(false);
  const focusRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>
        <input ref={focusRef} onFocus={() => setDown(true)} />
        {down && (
          <OutsideWrapper
            onOutside={() => setDown(false)}
            focusedRef={focusRef}
            className="input-wrapper"
          >
            children
          </OutsideWrapper>
        )}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const OutsideWrapper = ({ children, onOutside, className, focusedRef }) => {
  const wrapperRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [style, setStyles] = React.useState({
    opacity: 1
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1. component was mounted");
    const i = e => {
      console.log(e.target, wrapperRef.current);
      if (
        wrapperRef.current &&
        !wrapperRef.current.contains(e.target) &&
        focusedRef.current !== e.target
      ) {
        console.log("3. outside click was trigerred");
        e.preventDefault();
        setStyles({ opacity: 0 });
        setTimeout(() => {
          onOutside();
        }, 100);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", i, true);
    console.log("2. listener was added");
    return () => {
      console.log("4. listerner was removed");
      window.removeEventListener("click", i, true);
    };
  }, [onOutside, focusedRef]);
  return (
    <div
      ref={wrapperRef}
      style={style}
      className={`outside-wrapper ${className}`}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```